# Is OAuth consent screen verification required to use chrome webstore API in extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, chrome-web-store

I’m using Chrome Web Store API (specifically "User license get queries" request) to get info about extension license status. This is the only API enabled for this project, nothing else will be used.
I set everything up in Google cloud console, created credentials, pasted them into manifest. Everything works fine, but I’m planning to release extension soon and noticed that one should submit consent screen verification, otherwise warning will be shown to users.

**Do I have to submit verification (therefore fill Privacy Policy link) if I only plan to use this app to access chrome webstore purchases in extension and nothing else?**

Comment: If you are accessing a user's data, yes. I have not created a client that accesses Chrome webstore purchases, but that I am certain that action falls under the category of user data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John Hanley said, the verification is mandatory in order to retrieve information from your users, if you don't send the request your extension only will work with users within your domain, keep in mind that unverified apps only allow up to 100 users, after that you need to request a validation.

check these articles for more information about oauth2 validation process.

https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification